# SQLAlchemy ORM Collection Dict of Lists

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I'm attempting to create an ORM model to store a dictionary of lists in SQLAlchemy. I've had a little bit of progress based on https://gist.github.com/onecrayon/646da61accf54674d4f5098376a2c5df, but I'm stuck using the code below:

```py
import operator
from sqlalchemy import Column, ForeignKey, Integer, String, create_engine
from sqlalchemy.orm import relationship, sessionmaker
from sqlalchemy.ext.associationproxy import association_proxy
from sqlalchemy.orm.collections import MappedCollection, collection, _instrument_class
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base


connect_args = {}
connect_args["check_same_thread"] = False

engine = create_engine("sqlite:///test_orm.sqlite", connect_args=connect_args)
SessionLocal = sessionmaker(autocommit=False, autoflush=False, bind=engine)

db = SessionLocal()

Base = declarative_base()


class KeyedListCollection(MappedCollection):
    def __init__(self, key):
        super().__init__(operator.attrgetter(key))

    @collection.internally_instrumented
    def __setitem__(self, key, value, _sa_initiator=None):
        if not super().get(key):
            super().__setitem__(key, [], _sa_initiator)
        super().__getitem__(key).append(value)


_instrument_class(KeyedListCollection)


class Prop(Base):
    __tablename__ = "props"
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True, index=True)
    item_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey("items.id"))
    key = Column(String)
    value = Column(String)

    item = relationship("Item", back_populates="props")


class Item(Base):
    __tablename__ = "items"

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True, index=True)

    props = relationship(
        "Prop",
        collection_class=lambda: KeyedListCollection("key"),
        cascade="all, delete-orphan",
        back_populates="item",
    )

    @property
    def props_p(self):
        out = {}
        for k, vs in self.props.items():
            out[k] = [v.value for v in vs]
        return out


Base.metadata.create_all(bind=engine)

dat = {
    "props": {
        "p1": [
            "a",
            "b",
            "c",
        ],
        "p2": [
            "d",
            "e",
            "f",
        ],
    },
}


item = Item()
db.add(item)
db.commit()
db.refresh(item)

props = []
for k, vs in dat["props"].items():
    props.extend([Prop(key=k, value=v, item=item) for v in vs])
[db.add(p) for p in props]
db.commit()

item = db.query(Item).order_by(Item.id.desc()).first()
print(item.props_p)

db.delete(item)
db.commit()

db.close()
```

The `db.delete(item)` line raises `AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute '_sa_instance_state'`. I assume I have to add some sort of delete method to my custom mapper, but I don't know how. I tried overriding `__delitem__`, but that didn't seem to even get called.

The output from `print(item.props_p)` is what I'm looking for, but I don't think using a function in the model is the right way to do it because I can't use it the other way, i.e. feed it data with that schema (like the dictionary `dat` in the example) and have it stored properly.

I know I should be using an `association_proxy` in some way because I've done that combined with an `attribute_mapped_collection` to make a dictionary of strings, but I can't figure out how to make it work for a dictionary of lists.

Anyone got ideas for me?

Answer (score 0):

After more fiddling around, I changed `Item` to:

```py
class Item(Base):
    __tablename__ = "items"

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True, index=True)

    _props = relationship(
        "Prop",
        cascade="all, delete-orphan",
        back_populates="item",
    )

    @property
    def props(self):
        out = {}
        for p in self._props:
            if p.key not in out:
                out[p.key] = []
            out[p.key].append(p.value)
        return out

    @props.setter
    def props(self, props):
        ps = []
        for k, vs in props.items():
            ps.extend([Prop(key=k, value=v) for v in vs])
        self._props = ps
```

And that seems to do exactly what I want. I'm not sure that's the "right way", but it gets the job done.